# Oracle: Insert if not exist or Update not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to insert if the record not exist otherwise update for the following table.However it is saying 0
0 rows inserted.But   when I test my select statement it is returning 1 .

```
create table tb_coba2 (id number , nis number , nilai_b number , semester number);
```

Query :

```
insert into TB_COBA2 (nis , nilai_b , semester)
     select :nis , :nilai_a , :semester
      from dual
      where not exists (
       select 1 from tb_coba2
      where nis = :nis and semester = :semester
      );
      commit;


alter table tb_coba2 add constraint tb_coba2_uq unique ( nis, semester );
```

The following query returns 1 after first insert but if i run full insert it says 0 records inserted.

select 1 from tb_coba2
where nis = :nis and semester = :semester

What am i doing wrong here.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code does what it is meant to, that is: insert the row if the given `(nis, semester)` do not yet exist in the table.

However, your question mentions that you want to update as well, when a record already exists:

> I am trying to insert if the record not exist otherwise update

In Oracle, you would use a `merge` statement for this. Based on your description of the problem, that would be:

```
merge into tb_coba2 t
using (select :nis nis, :nilai_a nilai_a, :semester semester from dual) s
on (s.nis = t.nis and s.semester = t.semester)
when matched then update set t.nilai_a = s.nilai_a
when not matched then insert (nis, nilai_a, semester) values (s.nis, s.nilai_a, s.semester)
```

Comment: @Rocky4Ever: your existing query just handle the insert if not exists part of the question (and it does it correctly). However it won't update existing rows, which seems to be what you ask. Hence my suggestion to use `merge`.